# How to implement generic IEnumerable or IDictionary to avoid CA1006?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, fxcop, dapper

Out of curiosity i would like to know how to best implement a class that could be used to avoid the CA1006 warning

> CA1006 : Microsoft.Design : Consider a design where 'IReader.Query(String, String)' doesn't nest generic type 'IList(Of IDictionary(Of String, Object))'.

This is the method that returns the generic type

```
public virtual IList<IDictionary<string, object>> Query(
    string fullFileName, 
    string sheetName)
{
    using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(
        this.GetOdbcConnectionString(fullFileName)))
    {
        connection.Open();
        return connection
            .Query(string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                SystemResources.ExcelReader_Query_select_top_128___from__0_,
                sheetName))
            .Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>()
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Something like

```
SourceData<T, U> Query(string fullFileName, string sheetName)
SourceData Query(string fullFileName, string sheetName)
```

EDIT:

Following Marc's suggestions I encapsulated the nested generic in this class

```
public class QueryRow : List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    protected internal QueryRow(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> dictionary)
    {
        this.AddRange(dictionary.Select(kvp => kvp));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the intent of the list of dictionaries here? is that rows, with keyed values (i.e. cells accessed by column-name) ?

Comment: each dictionary is a row where each key is the column header and the value is the cell value

Comment: In place of `.Cast` can you not use `.ToDictionary`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, note that it is a design *guideline*, not a compiler error. One valid approach here would be: ignore it.

Another might be - encapsulate it; i.e. return a `List<QueryRow>`, where `QueryRow` is a shallow wrapper over an `IDictionary<string,object>` with an indexer, i.e.

```
public class QueryRow {
    private readonly IDictionary<string,object> values;
    internal QueryRow(IDictionary<string,object> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
    public object this[string key] {
        get { return values[key]; }
        set { values[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

then, since this is being accessed via dapper, fill via:

```
var data = connection.Query(....)
        .Select(x => new QueryRow((IDictionary<string,object>)x).ToList()
```

Another option (that I'm not hugely fond of), might be: return `DataTable`.

<sub>goes off to wash his hands after typing `DataTable`... gah! twice now</sub>

Comment: ok, i tried it this way. Does not work. I get this message 

`System.ArgumentNullException: 
Parametername: con
bei System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.Emit(OpCode opcode, ConstructorInfo con)
bei Dapper.SqlMapper.GetClassDeserializer(IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in SqlMapper.cs: line 1227.` when i add a parameterless constructor, Query<QueryRow> returns an IEnumerable<QueryRow> but the value property is null.

Comment: @mrt woah, totally didn't notice that this was "dapper". Nothing in the original question suggested "dapper" to me! But: in this case, you should be able to use the non-generic Query() method then cast each in turn, i.e. `connection.Query(....).Select(x => new QueryRow((IDictionary<string,object>)x).ToList()` - any use?

Comment: i thought the tag dapper would have been obvious :)

Comment: @mrt181 I obviously missed the tags